# Wordpress ajax success response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a contact form in Wordpress using wp_mail and Ajax

The email works but I'm having problems with the Ajax success response.

After the email is sent I need to show the user a message that the email was sent.

The Javascript to validate the form and show the success message:

```
    $atj(function(){
      $atj('#training-submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(verfiyFields()) {
            alert('here');
            requestData = {
              'action' : 'myajax-submit',
              'firstName' : $atj("#name").val(), 
              'email' : $atj("#email").val(), 
          }
          $atj.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, requestData).done(function(result){        
            result = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
            console.log(result);
            if(result == 'success'){
              $atj('.training-form [type=text]').val('');
              $atj('.training-form-message').append('<p class="training-form-complete-message">Thank you for the  email</p>');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    })



    //Verfiy 
    function verfiyTrainingFields() {
      var flag = true;

      var name =        $atj('#name');
      var email =       $atj('#email');

      if(name.val().indexOf(' ') === -1 ){
        name.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter name, first space last</p>');
        errorMessage($atj('.form-error'));
        flag = false;
      }
      if(!IsEmail(email.val())){
        email.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter valid email address</p>');
        errorMessage($atj('.form-error'));
        flag = false;
      }
      return flag;
    }
```

The `functions.php` file to send the email and send the ajax response.

```
    function myajax_submit() {

        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['firstName']);
        $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']);

        $headers[] = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n"; //Enables HTML ContentType. Remove it for Plain Text Messages

        $to = 'me@mysite.co.uk';

        $message = 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n" . 'email: ' . $email;

        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
        wp_mail( $to, 'Email Test', $message );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); 

        echo 'email sent';

        // generate the response
        $response = json_encode( array( 'success') );

        // response output
        header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
        echo $response;

        exit;
    }
```

The email is sent and the 'email sent' echo fires but the `if(result == 'success'){` in the js doesn't work.

The console.log(result) in the js file gives the following.

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'set_html_content_type' not found or invalid function name in <b>/Users/user.name/Desktop/MAMP-DocRoot/appname/src/php/wp-includes/plugin.php</b> on line <b>192</b><br />
email sent<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/user.name/Desktop/MAMP-DocRoot/appname/src/php/wp-includes/plugin.php:192) in <b>/Users/user.name/Desktop/MAMP-DocRoot/appname/src/php/wp-content/themes/sitename/functions.php</b> on line <b>66</b><br />
["success"]
```

Comment: Move this — `header( "Content-Type: application/json" );` to the top of your PHP file. You're getting an error because you're trying to send HTTP headers after you've already started outputting the body of your AJAX response (`echo 'email sent';`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `headers` after echo'in a response. Remove the 
`echo 'email sent';`

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `echo` statement as it's sending headers prematurely.

Then, you need to explicitly tell jQuery post to expect json back:

```
$atj.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, requestData).done(function(result){
    result = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
    console.log(result);
    if(result == 'success'){
        $atj('.training-form [type=text]').val('');
        $atj('.training-form-message').append('<p class="training-form-complete-message">Thank you for the  email</p>');
    }
}, 'json' );
```

Finally, your json encoded response will not give you your expected `response == success`. Instead, use `json_encode( array( 'success' => 1' ) );` and change your javascript to:

```
if( 1 == result.success ) ){
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
$.post( url, data, function( response ){
    if( 1 == response.success ){
      // Success - do something
    } else {
      // Failure
    }
}, 'json' );

<?php
function myAjaxFunction(){
    $result = array(
        'success' => 0 // Assume failure first
    );
    if( $_POST[ 'whatever' ] == 'what i want' ){
        $result[ 'success' ] = 1;
    }
    print json_encode( $result );
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Joe - New Nine, I tried your suggestion but I'm still not getting the response back in the js. In the console I get the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < '

Comment: I just tried the code I gave you and it worked perfectly. Change your post to the following and let me know what prints in the console:`$atj.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, requestData, function( result ){
        console.log( result );
      })`

Comment: Joe - New Nine, Apologies for the delay in responding, I tried your suggested code and I get null in the console.

Comment: In the jQuery post function, what happens if you get rid of the if statement and just print the result to the console. You should get an object back. If not, can you post more of your code? This very basic example works so there must be a problem elsewhere in the code and I'm happy to help you find it :)